# Calculate elapsed time in a completable future chain

Tags: java, completable-future, elapsedtime

I have several async api calls combined together in a completable futures chain. Each stage depends on the previous stage, i.e. if the previous call returned non-empty data, then we skip next call or make a call otherwise.

I want to measure not only the total time spent on the whole chain execution but also time spent on each api call individually.

How one can achieve that?

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class CompletableFutureApiCallsExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    var chain = apiCall1()
            .thenCompose(result1 -> {
                if (result1.isEmpty()) {
                    return apiCall2();
                } else {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result1);
                }
            })
            .thenCompose(result2 -> {
                if (result2.isEmpty()) {
                    return apiCall3();
                } else {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result2);
                }
            })
            .thenApply(CompletableFutureApiCallsExample::finalMapping);
    System.out.println(chain.get()); // return result
}

private static CompletableFuture<String> apiCall1() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "API Call 1 result");
}

private static CompletableFuture<String> apiCall2() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "API Call 2 result");
}

private static CompletableFuture<String> apiCall3() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "API Call 3 result");
}

private static String finalMapping(String result) {
    // do mapping and return result;
    return "Final result";
}
```

Comment: Just add `CompletionStages` in the beginning, between calls and the end that set start, intermediate and end times, respectively?

Comment: would it be possible to show any example?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a `Map<Call, Instant> timestamps` with an enum `Call`

```
enum Call {
 START,
 API_CALL_1,
 API_CALL_2,
 API_CALL_3,
 END
}
```

so in the end you have something like

```
START -> 12:17:01.123
API_CALL_1 -> 12:17:01.124
API_CALL_2 -> 12:17:03.242
API_CALL_3 -> 12:17:04.530
END -> 12:17:05.124
```

which will allow you to see how long each call took as well as the overall thing.

To do this, you can create something like a `CallTimer` which allows you to wrap each individual `CompletableFuture` into the associated enum value, like

```
class CallTimer {
 // use an EnumMap here but I'm too lazy to look up how to create one
 Map<Call, Instant> callTimes = new HashMap<>(); 

 public CallTimer() {
  callTimes.put(START, Instant.now());
 }

 // put start time into the map, but return the result of the actual call
 <T> CompletableFuture<T> wrap(CompletableFuture<T> call, Call id) {
   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Instant.now())
          .thenCompose(timestamp -> {
            calltimes.put(id, timestamp); 
            return call;
          });
 }

 void finished() {
  callTimes.put(END, Instant.now());
 }

 Map<Call, Instant> callTimes() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableMap(callTimes);
 }
}
```

and then for each call you perform in the main function, you use the timer's `wrap` instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CallTimer timer = new CallTimer();
    var chain = timer.wrap(apiCall1(), API_CALL_1)
            .thenCompose(result1 -> {
                if (result1.isEmpty()) {
                    return timer.wrap(apiCall2(), API_CALL_2);
                } else {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result1);
                }
            })
            .thenCompose(result2 -> {
                if (result2.isEmpty()) {
                    return timer.wrap(apiCall3(), API_CALL_3);
                } else {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result2);
                }
            })
            .thenApply(r -> {
               var result = finalMapping(r);
               timer.finished();
               return result;
             );
    System.out.println(chain.get()); // return result
    System.out.println(timer.callTimes()); // print times
}
```

I have not actually run or even compiled this so there's probably going to be some issues, but the general concept should be sound. You can also extend the `enum` and `wrap()` to track `API_CALL_1_START` and `API_CALL_1_END` by adding another `thenApply()` to put the end time after call completion.